# Sentence colon or comma

Tags: colons

Is this the best way to write this sentence below?

Moving forward, I hope to apply my experience to a cause that I am passionate about:  education.

Comment: Certainly not a comma; that would be the wrong intonation. A colon is OK, but it's overkill for one word. I'd use a dash.

Comment: I would personally use a colon as you did. (A comma is not right.)